# How to add more than 5 custom markers to Google Static Map

Tags: maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-static-api

I need to export a PDF file with a map with more than 5 custom icons. I used Google Static Map for this issue, but I have the limitation on the number of custom markers to show on the map.

Is there any solution for this? Any alternative solution using Google Maps?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi yanet, I found consulting the terms of google that no modification should be done to static maps images, section 10.5b https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions (regarding the solution offered before) but the good news is that there is already a feature request in the Issue Tracker that will be able to add more than 5 custom markers in a static map. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35817020

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info! I checked the issue and is open since 10 years ago, 2008! I need to resolve this on this month! So I decided not to use google static map and try to print the map using Google Map Javascript API.